# Cannot open readable database from fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to implement the database like in the following project

https://github.com/steventrigg/AlarmClock/tree/master/AlarmClock

I tried to use fragment instead of activity. But whenever i convert activity to fragment it cannot access the database.

I access the database with the following method

```
public AlarmModel getAlarm(long id) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); //error is shown here
String select = "SELECT * FROM " + Alarm.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + Alarm._ID + " = " + id;

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(select, null);

    if (c.moveToNext()) {
        return populateModel(c);
    }

    return null;
}
```

My fragment class is

```
public class AlarmListActivity extends Fragment {

private AlarmListAdapter=new AlarmDBHelper(getActivity());;
private AlarmDBHelper dbHelper;
private Context mContext;
ListView list;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mContext = getContext();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_alarm_list, container,
            false);
    list=(ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            startAlarmDetailsActivity(-1);

        }
    });

    mAdapter = new AlarmListAdapter(getActivity(),dbHelper.getAlarms(),AlarmListActivity.this);
    list.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Alarm List");

    return view;
}



    public void setAlarmEnabled(long id, boolean isEnabled) {
    AlarmManagerHelper.cancelAlarms(getActivity());

    AlarmModel model = dbHelper.getAlarm(id);
    model.isEnabled = isEnabled;
    dbHelper.updateAlarm(model);

    AlarmManagerHelper.setAlarms(getActivity());
}
```

In the logcat only it says it cannot get readable database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following line in your `onCreateView()`  method. Do not put it where you have put it.

```
private AlarmListAdapter=new AlarmDBHelper(getActivity());
```

Because it needs to get the context of your activity which is not available in the scope you declared it as `getActivity()` will not return the activity there.

Comment: thnx. this looks cleaner

Answer (score 0):

The "this" in this.getReadableDatabase refers to the Fragment - however, it needs a context which would be the activity.  try getActivity().getReadableDatabase();  otherwise put following method in fragment:

```
@Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        a=activity;
        super.onAttach(activity);
        }
```

And declare the public field

```
Activity a;
```

then a.getReadableDatabase() in your method

Comment: thank you. i think zahan safallwa's answer is easy to handle.